# How to avoid CSS inheritance to keep linear gradient background color intact?

Tags: html, css, background-color, linear-gradients

How to avoid CSS inheritance to keep linear gradient background-color intact?
Basically I want to avoid giving background color red from "box" (class name) div to `.box-child` div. I want `.box-child` to keep the initial background color set on `.main-box` div.

Normally I would just set background color back to what it was, but it is a linear gradient background and if I set it back on a small area it doesn't look what it is supposed to look like. I want to keep it intact.

```css
.main-box {
  color: white;
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient( 180deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(84, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.box {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.box-child {
  height: 150px;
  inherits: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  MAIN BOX
  <div class="box">
    BOX
    <div class="box-child">
      BOX CHILD
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t understand what is your goal and what is wrong. Can you describe what you  achieve?

Comment: I need .box-child to have the same background as .main-box. If I set .box-child background manually back to what it was it will start the gradient background all over again - I need it to keep .box-child inheriting background from .main-box NOT .box.

Comment: I need to use border-radius outwards and for that I need to use 2 divs - I thought this was much simpler example to show. If I didn't use linear gradient background then I would set background color back manually on .box-child and it would be solved.

Comment: you are probably overcomplicating a simple task, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51496204/8620333

Comment: I need something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071009/outward-border-radius-like-given-in-below-picture It isn't as simple as that to implement.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57440523/8620333

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I need the border radius outwards, not inner.

Comment: I’m not sure I totally understand. Are you basically wanting to cut a hole in box so that main shows through? Or is it just main’s background that should show?

Comment: Main background should show for .box-child. Basically what I am doing is having .box with different background so that I an create border radius outwards effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, the aim is to give the box-child element the same background as main - that is to give it that bit of main's background that it is sitting over.

This can be done if we give box-child a pseudo element that sits behind it but has the same dimensions, positioning and background as main and then add a clip-path to box-child to cut out those bits of the pseudo element that aren't within it.

```css
/* give the box-child before pseudo element the same dimensions and same background as main */
.main-box, .box-child::before {
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%,
    rgba(84, 9, 121, 1) 35%,
    rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%
  );
}

.main-box {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.box-child {
  height: 150px;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.box-child::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main-box">
    MAIN BOX
    <div class="box">
      BOX
      <div class="box-child">
        BOX CHILD
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```